# How to make order of parsed securities in Pandas-Datareader in original order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo, datareader

List of my securities is:

```
tickers =  ['TLW.L','WEIR.L','RMG.L','TSCO.L','STAN.L','CNA.L']
```

When I call pandas datareader to extract adj. close for each, I get a dataframe where all tickers are parsed in alphabetic order:

```
hist_prices = web.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', start, today)['Adj Close']
hist_prices.head()

           CNA.L    RMG.L   STAN.L  TLW.L   TSCO.L  WEIR.L
Date                        
2016-01-04  200.185 417.352 541.7   170.1   142.25  920.617
2016-01-05  202.733 417.543 532.3   164.4   144.40  897.940
2016-01-06  201.600 423.082 515.6   152.7   141.55  876.227
2016-01-07  198.391 418.880 505.8   150.0   139.20  842.452
2016-01-08  196.126 419.644 505.5   138.9   146.90  823.152
```

It is important for me to get the dataframe sorted in the original order of tickers as in defined list `tickers` in order to later multiply each price by  corresponding number of shares held in portfolio:

```
n_shares = [1000000, 200000, 1500000, 500000, 2000000, 1500000]
```

to get aggregated values and later perform portfolio analysis.

I have searched the docs to parse the assets in their original (non-alphabetical) state, but could not find a solution.

I could by all means do the multiplications manually, but if for example I had a list of 100 assets, that would be less feasible.

Please help me parse the tickers in original state, or if there is a better alternative solution, I would like to hear it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tickers` list in order to select your columns in a desired order:

```
In [6]: from pandas_datareader import data as web

In [7]: hist_prices = web.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-08') \
                         .loc['Adj Close'] \
                         [tickers]   # <------- NOTE

In [8]: hist_prices
Out[8]:
            TLW.L   WEIR.L    RMG.L  TSCO.L  STAN.L    CNA.L
Date
2016-01-04  170.1  920.617  417.352  142.25   541.7  200.185
2016-01-05  164.4  897.940  417.543  144.40   532.3  202.733
2016-01-06  152.7  876.227  423.082  141.55   515.6  201.600
2016-01-07  150.0  842.452  418.880  139.20   505.8  198.391
2016-01-08  138.9  823.152  419.644  146.90   505.5  196.126
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tickers` in the same `loc` with `'Adj Close'`

```
hist_prices = web.DataReader(
    tickers, 'yahoo', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-08'
).loc['Adj Close', :, tickers]

hist_prices.head()

            TLW.L   WEIR.L    RMG.L  TSCO.L  STAN.L    CNA.L
Date                                                        
2016-01-04  170.1  920.617  417.352  142.25   541.7  200.185
2016-01-05  164.4  897.940  417.543  144.40   532.3  202.733
2016-01-06  152.7  876.227  423.082  141.55   515.6  201.600
2016-01-07  150.0  842.452  418.880  139.20   505.8  198.391
2016-01-08  138.9  823.152  419.644  146.90   505.5  196.126
```